# ffmpeg 4.0.2 not stopping when network is down

Tags: ffmpeg, timeout

I'm using ffmpeg 4.0.2 on ArchLinux (installed from Arch repository)
I'm simulating a connection loss with `rfkill block all` while executing `ffmpeg -rw_timeout 10M -i https://server.com/path/playlist.m3u8 -c copy output.mkv`

ffmpeg waits forever without stopping. I've tried with `-stimeout` and `-timeout` but not working.

How can I make ffmpeg stop when network is down?

Comment: Unfortunately, theere's one network connection made to fetch the linked playlist and then child connections spawned to fetch variant playlists and media files. The protocol switches are only applied to the first task. You may consider this a bug. Consider opening a ticket at trac.ffmpeg.org

Comment: Here is the bug track: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/7516#ticket